# What is the use of software watchdog in a controller?

Tags: controllers, watchdog

Heyya,

I would like to what is the use of Software Watchdog and why they are used in controllers please..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean micro-controllers:

> A watchdog timer (sometimes called a computer operating properly or COP timer, or simply a watchdog) is an electronic timer that is used to detect and recover from computer malfunctions.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer)